# jq: join string array whether it is empty or not

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON `test.json` as follows:

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "a"
  }
]
```

And I would want to join the field `b` of each entry and handle the case of its
emptiness:

```
{  "a": "a",
  "b": "a, b, c"
},
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": null
}
```

The following command works...

```sh
cat test.json | 
      jq '.[] | .b as $t | if $t then {a: .a, b: $t | join(", ")} else {a: .a, b: $t} end'
```

... but it's too long as I have to write almost the same constructor two times.

I have tried to move the `if-then-else` conditional or even the `//` operator in the `{}` construction, but they result to a syntax error.

Comment: What's the desired output? Your code results in two separate objects that don't look like "join the field `b`".

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now: for each object, convert the value of `b` to a comma-separated string if it exists, and null otherwise?

Comment: And you do want multiple objects instead of an array of objects?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, I edited the question. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle `null`/`empty` values you could try these:

```
map(.b |= (. // [] | join(", ")))

map(if .b then .b |= join(", ") else . end)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `else .b = null` to match the desired output?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, probably. But it's not totally clear what the actual requirements are. I think a sane interpretation would be to "convert b to a comma separated string (if present)"